# Trying do build a contact form

Tags: php, forms, contact

I have some problem making my contact form work. The contact form should only be in one simple site. So i created two templates. 
The first template only has the form. 
The other one have the php code to send a mail. But i cant make the form contact the other template

Here is the first template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact 1
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content-container">
    <div id="content" role="main">


<form method="post" action="http://www.sbk-sm.se/lydnad-agility.2012/index.php/kontakt-2">
    Namn:
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br />
    Email:<br />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <br /> <br />

    Till:
    <select name="mailTo">
        <option value="adibbinhaider@gmail.com">Ex2 Mail</option>
        <option value="">Ex2 Mail</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    Meddelende:<br/>
    <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Skicka" name="submit">
</form>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #content-container -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the second template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact 2
*/
?>

<?php
    if($_POST["name"] != "")    
    {
        echo "Medelende har skickats ";
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $emailFrom = $_POST["email"];
        $mailTo = $_POST["mailTo"];

        $msg = "Från: \n";
        $msg .= "Namn: " .$name;
        $msg .= "\nE-Mail: " .$emailFrom;
        $msg .= "\n\n";     
        $msg .= "Till: \n";
        $msg .= $mailTo;
        $msg .= "\n\n";
        $msg .= "Meddelnde: \n";
        $msg .= $_POST["msg"];
        $msg .= "\n\n";

        $subject = utf8_decode("SM Lydnad & Agility 2012 Kontaktformulär");
        $headers = utf8_decode("From: " .$emailFrom."\r\n");

        mail($mailTo, $subject, utf8_decode($msg), $headers);

    }
?>
```

So I cant get to the second template, WP says the site doesnt exists

Comment: Is http://www.sbk-sm.se/lydnad-agility.2012/index.php/kontakt-2 the permalink to your second page? Also, this form can be very easily and very badly abused by spammers to send any message they want to any recipient they want. You may want to consider encoding the email recipient as, say, "person1" and then your php knowing that person1 is adibbinhaider@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to setup two pages, with two [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), one with your form code and the other with your mail code. The form action would point to the permalink of the page whose template hosts the mail code.

That said, I'd actually recommend using a plugin like [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) instead. It's highly modular and customizable and is a major time saver.

Comment: but i need a drop down menu with diffrente values, and the mail will be sent depending on who you want to mail

Comment: You can do that with a plugin, too. I highly encourage you to check out CF7, it is most definitely the path of least resistance.

Comment: hmm... just installed it but i coulnd find it :S

Comment: What couldn't you find?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a plugin like [contact form 7](http://contactform7.com/) or [gravity forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) instead? Otherwise, just have the page with the form do the form processing and submit the form to the page it's currently on. You'll need to register the templates correctly and what not, but that's as simple as putting /* Template Name: Your Template Name */ right after the opening PHP tag in your template and putting your template in your theme's root directory. You can also register templates using the `{page}_template` filter, which is useful if you're writing a plugin. See [this tutorial](http://www.unfocus.com/2010/08/10/including-page-templates-from-a-wordpress-plugin/) for more on that.

Comment: jinx buy me a coke

Comment: On it! I like your answer so much I think I'll upvote :D

Comment: Haha, well it's such a good ansewr I can only do the same to yours!